How to remove background pattern from every cell without removing background color in Excel?
A cell in Excel can have a background color, or it can have a pattern applied in the background with a "foreground" color to the pattern, or it can have both.


In an enormous worksheet with many cells with varying desirable background colors, I want to remove the pattern, if applied.
If I select all cells and choose "Automatic" for the Pattern color, it shows the current pattern using black. If I change the Pattern style to the "white" square, which represents a transparent pattern, there is no pattern seen on any cells…but all grid lines are "hidden" (overridden with white?) for all those cells the worksheet:

Is there any way to remove patterns while preserving grid lines and background colors across all selected cells?
I'm not looking for a scripting-based solution; my goal is to be able to "highlight" cells for executives using patterns, but then make it very easy to for the execs to completely remove with a few clicks.

If you manually add the cell borders, then your method preserves those. So, instead of the default lines, select the entire sheet and format the cell borders with outline and inside in a suitable colour, probably the grey from the top row of the default colours.

@Andrew-Morton, do you know when that became true? (It wasn't true when I was doing it, but I had to implement backward-compatible (xls) code.)

No, I have no idea when. But you wrote "not looking for a scripting-based solution" and your comment says "(xls) code". It certainly worked when I tried it with the (whatever they call it) home user Excel 365.

@AndrewMorton That might be a not-unacceptable hack. Thanks!

The default gridlines are tied to the cell fill, whether it is a solid fill or a pattern. If any fill is set, the default gridlines disappear.
Instead of gridlines, you can set and display the cell border. This is independent and is displayed with a fill as well. If you want to apply this setting to the entire worksheet, you can edit the Normal cell style and use the setting permanently (in the workbook).
Styles are defined in the workbook. If you want to use them in new workbooks, you can define a template file and use that template when you open a new workbook.

